# Can a כהן marry a גרושה בתולה

Tags: kohen-priest

We know that a  כהן   may only marry a woman who was not divorced.

However what about a case where a woman got married then got divorced  but never had relations.

Is she still fit for a cohen because technically she's a virgin?

Comment: you mean kohen gadol?

Comment: I edited out the false premise.

Comment: What was the intended question? Was it if a Gerusha Betula works for the Aseh of a Kohein Gadol?

Comment: @DannySchoemann Usually the way to respond to false premeses is by answering them.

Answer (score 4):

Explicitly forbidden in the Rambam ([Isurei Bi'a Ch.19:](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5119.htm)2)

> שכל נשואה בחזקת בעולה, אף על פי שנמצאת בתולה

She is forbidden to **any** Cohen once she was divorced. As the Ramabm states ibid ([17:13](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/5117.htm)) that even if she was divorced after the Eirusin, the is forbidden to a Cohen.

> אחת גרושה מן האירוסין, או מן הנישואין

Comment: "_Becheskas be'ula_", but what if we know for sure that she is a _besula_, e.g. she was under 3 years old at the time of the _get_?

Comment: @NBZ - actually that part of the answer was before we edited the question; and then you'd be correct, if I'm reading the Rambam correctly. But as the question stands now, I don't see any difference in the Rambam - regarding divorcees - whether they are under or above 3 years old.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38079/3073